# How to get the ESP8266 to work in update mode?

Tags: arduino, wifi, esp8266

I have been trying to get my WiFi module, ESP8266 to work in the "update mode" where you connect GPIO_0 to ground.
The board is functional when GPIO_0 is disconnected from ground and I am able to use AT commands to talk to it via the Arduino serial monitor.
Following is what it prints upon connecting:

```
 ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:4, boot mode:(3,6)

wdt reset
load 0x40100000, len 1396, room 16 
tail 4
chksum 0x89
load 0x3ffe8000, len 776, room 4 
tail 4
chksum 0xe8
load 0x3ffe8308, len 540, room 4 
tail 8
chksum 0xc0
csum 0xc0

2nd boot version : 1.4(b1)
  SPI Speed      : 40MHz
  SPI Mode       : DIO
  SPI Flash Size & Map: 8Mbit(512KB+512KB)
jump to run user1 @ 1000

rrlÌÿ
Ai-Thinker Technology Co.,Ltd.

ready
```

However, I cannot do most things as the firmware is out of date.
As a result, I am trying to update it (with no success)

When I set it to update mode and use the python tool "**[esptool.py](https://github.com/themadinventor/esptool)**", the script fails to connect to the ESP board. 
Following is the command:

```
python esptool.py -p /dev/ttyUSB0 write_flash 0x00000 "/home/aditya/Desktop/v0.9.2.2 AT Firmware.bin"
```

Following is the output:

```
Connecting...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "esptool.py", line 532, in <module>
    esp.connect()
  File "esptool.py", line 159, in connect
    raise Exception('Failed to connect')
Exception: Failed to connect
```

I have even run the Windows counterpart of this tool "**[ESP Flasher](http://www.xess.com/blog/esp8266-reflash/)**" with no luck

The one who helps will be given a cookie (unless you value privacy)

Answer (score 0):

This tool (esptool.py) works with a ROM bootloader, which is only started if GPIO_0 is tied to the GND *during hardware reset*. Bootloader also times out pretty fast, so just connecting GPIO_0  to the ground is not enough.

For me, following works:

1. Connect TXD/RXD/GND/VCC to the PC and CH_PD to VCC;
2. Make sure I can talk to the firmware via terminal (picocom/minicom/etc);
3. Connect GPIO_0 to the GND;
4. Connect RST to GND;
5. Release RST;
6. Run esptool.py

If still no dice, swap 5 and 6 above, i.e. first run esptool.py, then (as quickly as possible) release/disconnect RST. You will only have a second or two before esptool.py times out.

Answer (score 0):

Try making the ground of all devices connected: if you have a level shifter inbetween, make sure the GND is tied to the GND of Arduino and also to the RS232 GND.